# By evaluating $\int_0^1 e^{2\sqrt x} \ dx$, deduce the exact value of $\int_{1}^{e^2} (\ln y)^2 \ dy$.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Starting with the evaluation of the first integral:

Let $u = \sqrt{x} \Rightarrow dx = 2u \ du$. Then

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 e^{2\sqrt x} \ dx &= \int_0^1 2ue^{2u} \ du \\
&= ue^{2u}\Big|_0^1 - \int_0^1 e^{2u} \ du \\
&= ue^{2u}\Big|_0^1 - \frac 1 2 e^{2u}\Big|_0^1 \\
&= \left[(1)e^{2(1)} - (0)e^{2(0)}\right] - \left[\frac 1 2 e^{2(1)} - \frac 1 2e^{2(0)}\right] \\
&= e^2 - \left(\frac 1 2 e^2 - \frac 1 2\right) \\
&= \frac 1 2 e^2 + \frac 1 2
\end{align*}

I am a little bit unsure of the steps to follow for the evaluation of the second integral. The upper and lower limits seem to hint at the application of the inverse function to obtain a similar expression in terms of $e^{2 \sqrt x}$, but I have been unable to find a suitable substitution to make it work.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: $y = e^{2\sqrt x} \implies\ln y = 2\sqrt x \implies x = (\ln y)^2/4$

Comment: Got it, the substitution works! Thank you. Could I ask whether this is a general method for solving for integrals of inverse functions (i.e. using $u$-substitution of the inverse function $F^{-1}(x)$? I found a possibly related link here: https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_function_integration_formula but I'm unsure if it is the same thing.

Comment: It seems so (do take note of the injectivity requirement). [The Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions) contains a bit more info on this method.

Comment: That seems to be much more useful. Thank you, once again!